# HTMLtableCell is not working for table header (th) in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have repeater control that have table with table header(th) and table cell(td). I want to access td and th in code. I use HTMLTableCell for both in repeater code, I can access the td, but th is not working. Any suggestions
Here is the code sample:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeater_ItemDataBound" >
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table id="tbl" >
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="header1" runat="server">head 1/th>
      <th">Head 2</th>
 </tr>
    </thead>  
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td id="td1" runat="server" ><asp:Literal ID="litTD1" runat="server" /></td>
      <td  ><asp:Literal ID="litTD2" runat="server" /></td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </table>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

in code behind

HtmlTableCell header1= e.Item.FindControl("header1") as HtmlTableCell;
HtmlTableCell td1= e.Item.FindControl("td1") as HtmlTableCell;
```

This code works for td1 (which is cell) but object null reference exception on header1
Sorry, I do have runat="server" for th

Comment: There should only be one table header... it should not repeat. View source and see what's being rendered?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `runat="server"` attribute if you want to access it in code-behind.

Comment: Sorry for typo, I do have runat="server" attribute for th

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `e.Item.FindControl("header1")` will not return anything, because your `header1` table header isn't part of `e.Item` (which essentially contains the rendered contents of the `ItemTemplate`). You need to be searching the control tree for the Repeater, not the individual item.

Comment: How should I approach? Can you give me an example or sample code, or explain little more.